# Azure DevOps Through curl or get task output value as new variable

Tags: bash, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I need to go through the curl restAPI and do content grep and cut certain characters to get a new token value as a variable
But I don't know how to make curl, grep, cut ... operations in the variables

Is the logic of doing these operations in variables feasible?

EX.

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: GetToken
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 
        token= curl -H $HEADER -D $DATA www.example.com | grep -oEi $pattern | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d '"' -f 2
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=token;]$token
```

Or can I get the value of task output to set a new variable?
ex.

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: CreateToken
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 
       curl --header $HEADER --data "{userKey:$USERKEY,orgToken:$ORGTOKEN,requestType:getAllProducts}" $API |grep -oEI "\"productName\":\"$PRODUCTNAME\",\"productToken\":\"[0-9a-f]*\"" | cut -d ':' -f 3 | cut -d '"' -f 2

Output
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/a6f13e9c-2c45-4ac7-9674-42de3efe2503.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   147    0     0  100   147      0    158 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   158
100 13655    0 13508  100   147  12577    136  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 12714

33234d4db39844cf8c73c54e398c44c248ab368f319a4af7b9646cb461fa60b9 //I want to get this value as new variable

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: GetCreateToken
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script:
        Token= $CreateToken
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=token;]$token
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly your question is regarding on how to pass the output of a shell script into a variable to be consumed by other tasks?
If so you may change the question title into some like " Azure DevOps pipeline - passing shell script output into variables" to be more help other to find an anwser.

Anyway, try it this way:

```yaml
- bash: Bash@3
  displayName: GetToken
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 
        # Note the $() around the call of curl, grep and cut. If you want to assign the result of a call, then encapsulate it into $()
        token=$(curl -H $HEADER -D $DATA www.example.com | grep -oEi $pattern | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d '"' -f 2)
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=token;]$token"

  # Just a side note: This is the short-hand syntax for using the bash task
- bash: |
    echo "$(token)"
```

See also the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script) on how to set pipeline variable in script tasks.
If you want to use a variable in another job, then the syntax is a bit different and [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable):

```yaml
- job: A
  steps:
  - bash: |
      token=$(curl -H $HEADER -D $DATA www.example.com | grep -oEi $pattern | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d '"' -f 2)
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=token;isOutput=true]$token"
    displayName: GetToken
    name: gettoken # you have to give the task a name to be able to access it through dependencies object below

- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    token: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['gettoken.token'] ]
```

You may also have a look at [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash).

Comment: @eddy chi Just a friendly reminder, to respond by either commenting or accepting the anwser.

Comment: Could you do the same with the `script` task instead of the `bash` task?

Comment: @Stevy Of course. Script task will execute as Bash on a linux build agent and AFAIR uses CMD on Windows hosts.
The syntax might be a bit different. Don't remember how to print variables CMD style.
Maybe this link is helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable